# Using access-methods feature in eclipselink jpa, why it EL calls methods multiple times?

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping, eclipselink

Thanks in advance. 
I am trying to use "access-methods" using get & set methods for a field in my java object. 
My question is I noticed EclipseLink is calling the getter method multiple times while storing to database. It stores only once in db.
And it also calling setter method during "WRITING TO" data base. Which I expect only be called  during "reading from" data base to build back object.

Here is sample code I have

```
<entity-mappings ><basic name="column1" />
<basic name="longstring" >
            <column name="col2" nullable="true"   />
            <access-methods get-method="getLongString" set-method="setLongString" />
        </basic>

public class TestObj {
    String column1; 
    String col2;
public String getLongString() {  return "some long string";  }
public void setLongString(String col2) {  this.col2 = col2;  } 
}
```

any idea what exactly EclipseLink does internally and why it tries to call 'set' method during writing to db? and also multiple times?

thanks

Gopi

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink must use your access methods to get and set the values within the entity and any cones it needs to make to track changes and for maintaining the shared cache.  The stack trace when the methods are called will give you an indication of why its being used.